# In Symfony, conditionally require the fields of an included form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form type class (let's call it "ClientType") which includes another form type class ("PhoneType").  PhoneType is part of ClientType like this:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('phoneVoice', new PhoneType);
}
```

I would like to set this up so that PhoneType's required fields apply IFF at least one of the PhoneType fields is filled out.  For example, PhoneType might include country code, number, and extension.  If any of those fields is filled out, I'd like PhoneType's required fields (country code and number) to be required.

How can I set this up?  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT - adding in the form type classes**

**ClientType**

```
<?php

namespace AppName\ClientBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use AppName\ClientBundle\Form\Type\PhoneType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ClientType extends AbstractType {

   /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('phoneVoice', new PhoneType, ['required' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppName\ClientBundle\Entity\Client',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'client';
    }

}
```

**PhoneType**

```
<?php

namespace AppName\ClientBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class PhoneType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('countryCode', new PhoneCountryCodeType, [
                    'preferred_choices' => ['1'],
                    'empty_value' => '1'
                ])
                ->add('number', 'number', [
                    'required' => true,
                    'max_length' => 10
                ])
                ->add('extension', 'number')
                ->add('isPrimary');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppName\ClientBundle\Entity\PhoneRecord'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'phone';
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us the code you are working on so we van help you.

Comment: Added in the form type classes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As i see, your PhoneType mapped to PhoneRecord entity, so you can use custom [validation mechanism](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Example of your case:

```
//AppName\ClientBundle\Entity\PhoneRecord.php

public function isCreditsLegal()
{
    if ($this->countryCode || $this->number || $this->extension) {
         return $this->countryCode && $this->number;
    }
    return true;
}


#validation.yml

AppName\ClientBundle\Entity\PhoneRecord:
    getters:
        creditsLegal:
            - "True": { message: "Invalid credits" }
```